# HttpComponents Custom SSLSocketFactory

Tags: ssl, keystore, apache-httpcomponents

Per the example at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

```
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
```

Should instantiate a SSLSocketFactory using my custom trust store, yet when I try to build my project, I get the error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory is abstract; cannot be intantiated
```

Is the example out of date? Does it work for other people?

Comment: maybe you're using the wrong SSLSocketFactory (the one that comes with JDK)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a [`org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) you should use, not a [`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) (see `import` directive in the example file you're using).

Note that the former has constructors that can use the latter if you already have existing code for this. However, you would generally get a custom `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` from an `SSLContext`, so you might as well use the `SSLContext`-based constructor in this case.